# Dynamic JTable extending AbstractTableModel

Tags: java, swing, dynamic, jtable, abstracttablemodel

I would like to make a JTable which can add rows to itself dynamically,initially the table should have no data in it.
I did this by creating a TableModel class extends AbstractTableModel, code is attached.

```
class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel{

    private static int initialRowCount = 3;
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> data;
    private static String[] columnName = {"Date Tested","Product","VI Test Result","Lot ID","MCN","SLT TIS","Tester","In","First Pass","FP%","RT1 Pass","RT2 Pass","Final Pass",
        "SLT Final Yield %","SLT Fail Quantity","Remark"};
    int i=0;

    public MyTableModel(){
        data = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>(20);
    }

    public int getColumnCount() {
        System.out.println(i++);
        return columnName.length;
    }

    public int getRowCount() {
        return initialRowCount;
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int r, int c) {

    }

    public String getColumnName(int c) {
        return columnName[c];
    }    

    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
        if(column==0)
            return false;
        else
        return true;
    }

    public void setValueAt(Object vaule,int row,int column){
        data.add();
    }

    public void addRow(){
        initialRowCount++;
    }
}
```

My question is, must I use a 2-D ArrayList as a data container? If so, How should I implement it in this code?
I am new to Java and just start learning Swing, any help is appreciated.

Comment: `DefaultTableModel` internally uses a `Vector` within a `Vector`.  If you don't know the actual data type for the row (ie it's not a standard POJO), then I'd suggest using something similar.  In fact, just use a `DefaultTableModel` instead...

Comment: Thanks for the timely response, I would like have the flexibility to do something else, so I need to write my own TableModel.
Is ArrayList of object array possible in this case, because I only extend the rows.

Comment: I'd use a `List` of `List` for simplicty

Comment: there are two ways, 1. using DefaultTableModel, 2. override notifiers for view in setValueAt and addRow, 3. type of underlaying array isnt important for AbstractTableModel (excluding HashMap or HashWhatever == havent indexing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try next simple example of `JTable` with custom `TableModel`(`MyModel`) which allow add/remove rows and cols. Data of row stored in wrapped object(`RowData`). Filtering and sorting does not supported in model, but you can simply add them.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;


public class TestFrame extends JFrame{

    private MyModel model;
    private JTable table;

    public TestFrame(){
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        init();
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void init() {
        table = new JTable(model = new MyModel());

        JButton add = new JButton("add row");
        add.addActionListener(getAddListener());
        JButton remove = new JButton("remove row");
        remove.addActionListener(getRemoveListener());
        JButton addC = new JButton("add column");
        addC.addActionListener(getAddColListener());
        JButton removeC = new JButton("remove column");
        removeC.addActionListener(getRemoveColListener());

        add(new JScrollPane(table));
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.add(add);
        p.add(remove);
        p.add(addC);
        p.add(removeC);
        add(p,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    private ActionListener getRemoveColListener() {
        return new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int selectedColumn = table.getSelectedColumn();
                if(selectedColumn != -1){
                    stopEditing();
                    model.removeColumn(selectedColumn);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    private ActionListener getAddColListener() {
        return new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                model.addColumn();
            }
        };
    }

    private ActionListener getRemoveListener() {
        return new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int selectedRow = table.getSelectedRow();
                if(selectedRow != -1){
                    stopEditing();
                    model.removeRow(selectedRow);
                }
            }

        };
    }

    private ActionListener getAddListener() {
        return new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                model.addRow();
            }
        };
    }

    private void stopEditing() {
        TableCellEditor cellEditor = table.getCellEditor();
        if(cellEditor != null){
            cellEditor.stopCellEditing();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... strings) {
        new TestFrame();
    }

    private class RowData{

        private Map<Integer, Object> values = new HashMap<Integer, Object>();

        public Object getValueForCol(int columnIndex) {
            if(values.containsKey(columnIndex)){
                return values.get(columnIndex);
            }
            return "";
        }

        public void setValueForCol(Object aValue, int columnIndex) {
            values.put(columnIndex, aValue);
        }

    }

    private class MyModel extends AbstractTableModel{

        int colIndex=0;
        private List<Integer> cols = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        private List<RowData> rows = new ArrayList<TestFrame.RowData>();

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int column) {
            return cols.get(column).toString();
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return rows.size();
        }

        public void addRow() {
            rows.add(new RowData());
            fireTableRowsInserted(rows.size(), rows.size());
        }


        public void removeRow(int selectedRow) {
            rows.remove(selectedRow);
            fireTableRowsDeleted(selectedRow, selectedRow);
        }

        public void removeColumn(int selectedColumn) {
            cols.remove(table.convertColumnIndexToModel(selectedColumn));
            fireTableStructureChanged();
        }

        public void addColumn() {
            cols.add(++colIndex);
            fireTableStructureChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return cols.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            RowData rowData = rows.get(rowIndex);
            return rowData.getValueForCol(cols.get(columnIndex));
        }

        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            RowData rowData = rows.get(rowIndex);
            rowData.setValueForCol(aValue,cols.get(columnIndex));
            fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, columnIndex);
        }

    }
```