# Horizontal scroll bar wont show on a dynamic table

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable, user-experience

I am trying to make a dynamically growing JTable, specifically, growing columns. However, I've stumbled upon a problem where If my JTable grows too big, all the columns are compressed and the cell wont be visible any more. I initially based code from the best answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443008/adding-columns-to-jtable-dynamically?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa). Additionally, I tried to altered the code and placed it on the viewport of the scrollpane and it did not work. This was it.

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[] { "Initial Column" }, 5);
JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);
scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Table Column Add");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setBounds(100, 100, 600, 300);
frame.add(scrollPane);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Afterwards, I saw another solution on dynamic JTables. I tried running the best answer on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23511143/dynamic-jtable-extending-abstracttablemodel?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) and it's the same thing, when then columns get too big, it will be compressed.

However, if you keep adding rows, the scroll bar would appear and the row height is maintained and not compressed.

Comment: You need to turn off auto-resizing by calling [setAutoResizeMode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setAutoResizeMode-int-).

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @VGR Thank you so much!